# How to parse Comma delimited string with newline to JSON in PHP to use with Morris.JS

Tags: php, json, parsing, morris.js

I send SOAP API requests to a Service, but the response comes in one field  and consists of a string :

```
$string = '"users","actions","movements" "user1","111","54" "user2","87","123" "user3","92","23"'
```

when i do:

```
$json = json_encode($string);
```

does not result in valid `JSON`.

I've tried :

```
$Data = str_getcsv($incomingdata, "," , '"' , "\n"); 
$json2 = json_encode($Data);
```

It is not parsed correctly to use with MORRIS.JS and results in complete rubbish

The "users","actions","movements" are the headers.
Could someone point me in the right direction please ?

The needed result should look like this:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [user] => user1
            [actions] => 630
            [movements] => 87
        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [user] => user2
            [actions] => 330
            [movements] => 187
        )
```

and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I finally made it happen this way:**

```
<?php
include("functions.php");

$data = MYFunction('Template','FilterBy','SortBy','Colums'); //here DATA FROM SOAP
//............
//............
$data = $pickrate;
file_put_contents('file.csv', $pickrate); // placing acquired data to CSV
$csv= file_get_contents('file.csv'); //open saved csv file
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv)); //create array map and explode on \n

if (($handle = fopen('file.csv', 'r')) === false) {
    die('Error opening file'); // no access error handling
}

$headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ','); //generate headers from first row delim, by ","
$complete = array(); //opening array

while ($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1024, ',')) { //read each row delim by ","
    $complete[] = array_combine($headers, $row); // push it into var $complete and combine $headers row with $row
}

fclose($handle); // closes the array gen

//include this file and then call <? echo json_encode($complete); ?> in Morris.js DATA field
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoud put the example of json expected, in any case, maybe this helps you:

```
$string = '"users","actions","movements"
"user1","111","54"
"user2","87","123"
"user3","92","23"';

// in case of csv where rows are delimited with new lines use explode( "\n", $string )
// if is delimited with space character use explode( ' ', $string )
$array = array_map( 'str_getcsv', explode( "\n", $string ) );
array_shift( $array );

array_walk( $array, function( &$v, $k, $keys ) {
    $v = array_combine( $keys, $v );
}, [ 'user', 'actions', 'movements' ] );


print_r( $array );
/*
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user] => user1
            [actions] => 111
            [movements] => 54
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user] => user2
            [actions] => 87
            [movements] => 123
        )

    ...
)
*/

print_r( json_encode( $array ) );
/* 
[
    {"user":"user1","actions":"111","movements":"54"},
    {"user":"user2","actions":"87","movements":"123"},
    {"user":"user3","actions":"92","movements":"23"}
]
*/
```

Comment: hmm this looks sound except : :  array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements in ...( $array[$k] = array_combine( $keys, $v );)

Comment: With your solution i came rly close except for that PHP warning.
Could you please look at the question i've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your string to an array before encode with [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), try to use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) instead:

```
$result = explode(',', $string);
$json = json_encode($result);
```

If you don't want to ignore new lines:

```
$result = explode(' ', $string);
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $item){
  $resultJ[$i] = explode(',', $item);
  $i++;
}
$json = json_encode($resultJ);
```

To remove the slashes and \n's in your json:
You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) in the json:

```
str_replace(array("\\", "\n"), "", $json);
```

or in the $string (recommended), because yours \ is an natural escaping to " by json encoding:

```
str_replace('"', "", $string);
```

QUESTION UPDATED, ANSWER TOO:

```
    <?php
$string = str_replace('"', "", '"users","actions","movements" "user1","111","54" "user2","87","123" "user3","92","23"');
$result = explode(' ', $string);
$result2 = array();
$i = 0;
//Load the arrays
foreach ($result as $item) {
  $result2Array[$i] = explode(',', $item);
  $i++;
}
$total = count($result2Array) - 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++) {
  $j = 0;
  //Bring values to each index
  foreach ($result2Array[0] as $index){
    $resultF[$i-1][$index] = $result2Array[$i][$j];
    $j++;
  }
}


var_dump($resultF);
$json = json_encode($resultF);
```

Comment: I'm trying now.

Comment: Hmm how to escape those slaashes and \n's ?
[["\"user\"","\"actions\"\n\"user1\"","\"265\"\n\"user2\"","\"198\"\n"]]

Comment: You can use str_replace in the json:

str_replace(array("\\", "\n"), "", $json);

or in the $string (recommended):
str_replace('"', "", $json);

Comment: Updated to fill your actual needs